# Django: using items in list without executing for loop in view

Tags: django, loops, templates, view

Apologies for the unclear title, I'm not sure how to articulate my question in a few words.

Basically, within my view I have a variable containing a list of objects (photos):

```
photos = Photo.objects.all()
```

In my template I have a for loop for these objects where I display the attributes (e.g. photo.author ). I would like to have some logic to be run on individual photo instances:

```
all_likes = Like.objects.all()
for photo in photos:
    pic_likes = all_likes.filter(photo_id=id)
    like_count = len(pic_likes)
    liker = pic_likes.filter(liker_id=request.user.id)
    if len(liker) != 0:
        liked=True
```

but using a for loop inside the view causes the error

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

How should I go about having logic for the photo instances but not the object list as a whole?

My Photo model is as follows:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploaded_images', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default = 1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
```

and my like model is:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='liker')
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='photo')
    liked = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you want here. You want to know if any of the photos was liked at all (this is basically what the `liked` variable does I think)? Or the like count of individual photos (for a given user?)?

Comment: You have a bug in your code somewhere. Where is `id` set? Rather than querying for likes by id, try using the reverse accessor on photo. Probably something like `photo.like_set.all()`.

Comment: You probably better also provide the models for `Photo` and `Like`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would like to run the line 'pic_likes = all_likes.filter(photo_id=id)' on the individual photo instances/list items. Putting the for loop in the view, however, just causes errors and I suspect that using the variable liked within a _second_ for loop in my template will be troublesome.

Comment: @Chris that's a great idea! I think I will still need to reference particular instances (photo.like... not photo**s**.like....) which is what I'm not sure how to do

Comment: Change the `related_name` on `Like.photo` to `'likes'`. That is how you will refer to the set of `Likes` related to each photo. Then query it in your loop with `photo.likes.all()`. Now you have all the likes for that photo. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `request.user`. Are you trying to only get the likes that the current user created? If so then you can filter on the reverse accessor: `photo.likes.filter(liker=request.user)`

Comment: This is the buggy line,  pic_likes = all_likes.filter(photo_id=id). Since id is not defined, it uses the global id funciton

Comment: @eran I was under the impression that this references the id of the photo

Comment: @FANCY_HOOMAN what is the context of your code?

Comment: @FANCY_HOOMAN, BTW. you are using the related_name in wrong way. It should be the name you want to use in the foreign object.

Comment: @ eran This is code for an instagramesque website where you can post photos, and browse photos posted by others. 

In reference to related_name, I actually have no idea what it does (I'm pretty new to django), I just got errors without it.

Comment: @FANCY_HOOMAN related_name is the name you use to access from the foreign object. For example, if you write (in class Like), photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='likes'), then in the Photo instance, you access its likes using photo.likes.all()

Comment: @eran I see, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change the `related_name` attributes in you `Like` model, maybe even remove it to use the default names:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    liked = models.BooleanField()
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
all_likes_of_a_user = user_instance.like_set.all()
all_likes_of_a_photo = photo_instance.like_set.all()
```

---

Now, to iterate over the photos in the view, you can use:

```
for photo in Photo.objects.all():
    like_count = photo.like_set.count()
    has_liked = photo.like_set.filter(liker=request.user).exists()
```

And for using that in your templates, you could add a nested loop:

```
{% for photo in Photo.objects.all %}
    Like count: {{ photo.like_set.count }}
    Has this user liked this photo:
    {% for like in photo.like_set.all %}
        {% if like.liker == user %}
        yes
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or add a method to your `Photo` model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    def users_that_liked_it(self):
        return [
            e.liker.pk
            for e in self.like_set.all()]

{% for photo in Photo.objects.all %}
    Like count: {{ photo.like_set.count }}
    Has this user liked this photo:
    {% if user.pk in photo.users_that_liked_it %}
        yes
    {% else %}
        no
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for giving such a comprehensive answer.